# CSS style to outline a span

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a text highlight, but the CSS to do it completely escapes me. Here is a sample of the HTML:

```
This is a long <span class="selection">piece of text, whose sole purpose is being long enough to wrap over several lines,</span> so I can illustrate my problem.
```

And the CSS:

```
.selection {
  background: lightblue;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  border: solid blue thin;    
}
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is an outline for the area covered by the span, like this:
[image: Desired effect]

But instead, the border is replicated in-between lines:
[image: Result of CSS]

Then I figured I'll just remove the `border` from my CSS, which would give me this:
[image: Compromise]

But in reality it looks just as odd:

[image: Result of CSS without the border]

I understand conceptually what is going on; the span includes only the text, not the line spacing. My CSS skills don't go much further than the snippet above, but is there really no way to get rid of those border lines in-between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `outline` instead of `border` to achieve the desired look & feel.
[I took the snippet from Hitmands answer and changed it a little bit]

```css
.text-highlighted {
  background: cyan;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  padding: .2em .4em;
}

.entry { max-width: 200px; padding: .5em; }
```

```html
<div class="entry">This is a long <mark class="text-highlighted">piece of text, whose sole purpose is being long enough to wrap over several lines,</mark> so I can illustrate my problem.</div>
```

Comment: Cool!! Always hated that `outline` property, but I guess the underdog's got its own use.

Comment: Ha! I even used the word outline in my title ;) Works like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use proper markup... **span** is a generic inline tag, but, for highlighting text you should use **mark** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark

```css
.text-highlighted {
  background: cyan;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  padding: .2em .4em;
}

.entry { max-width: 200px; padding: .5em; }
```

```html
<div class="entry">This is a long <mark class="text-highlighted">piece of text, whose sole purpose is being long enough to wrap over several lines,</mark> so I can illustrate my problem.</div>
```

Comment: still, gives the same look & feel as `span`. (+1 for `mark` thought)

Comment: I didn't even know the `mark` tag existed, so perhaps my HTML skills don't extend so far either ;), but I don't see that your answer gives a different result. I see the point of the extra vertical padding, but running your snippet and resizing the window to let the text wrap gives the same result as I had with the `span` tag. Except that it overlaps the line above.